# Google Analytics API for commercial website

Tags: api, google-analytics, e-commerce, policy, google-analytics-api

This question is for anyone that used Google Analytic API on a commercial website.

For instance you have a website where members can upload music and pay for a membership to track  via Analytics how many people visited their uploads.

Does Google allow to use the Analytics API for commercial use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The Analytics API may be used for both commercial and noncommercial purposes in ways consistent with these API Terms.

http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gdata/gdataTermsOfService.html

Answer (score 2):

Please refer to the lengthy [Terms of Service](http://www.google.com/analytics/tos.html) :)

**EDIT:** As @yc pointed out, this is a question toward the the API (thanks btw).

While I don't think my original answer is totally correct, I think it is worth mentioning the "Privacy" paragraph in the "Regular" Analytics TOS:

> 1. PRIVACY . You will not (and will not allow any third party to) use the
>      Service to track or collect personally
>      identifiable information of Internet
>      users, nor will You (or will You allow
>      any third party to) associate any data
>      gathered from Your website(s) (or such
>      third parties' website(s)) with any
>      personally identifying information
>      from any source as part of Your use
>      (or such third parties' use) of the
>      Service. You will have and abide by an
>      appropriate privacy policy and will
>      comply with all applicable laws
>      relating to the collection of
>      information from visitors to Your
>      websites. You must post a privacy
>      policy and that policy must provide
>      notice of your use of a cookie that
>      collects anonymous traffic data.

I am by no means a lawyer, but just want to point out that you need to be careful about what data you collect.  Especially when using [Event Tracking](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/eventTrackerGuide.html) and [Custom Variables](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/gaTrackingCustomVariables.html).

Comment: This is not for the Google Analytics API; it's just for regular ol' Google Analytics.

Answer (score 1):

From the [API page](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gdata/gdataFAQ.html):

> **What does the Google Analytics Data
>   Export API cost?**
>    The Google Analytics
>   Data Export API is free. We intend to
>   always provide a basic level of
>   service for free. As we continue to
>   build out more advanced features and
>   functionality, we may revisit this
>   later.